# Symlinks with a custom root

Tags: symlink, chroot

I have a project at `/long/ass/path/to/project` that has many soft links within it.

Whenever I need to run a new batch in the project I create a link from the output of the last batch to the input of the new batch as so:

(From within: `/long/ass/path/to/project/stage5`:)
   `ln -s ../../stage4/output  ./input/`

Relative links don't hold very well when being moved around, so I tend to go for absolute links like so:

(From within: `/long/ass/path/to/project/stage5`:)
   `ln -s /long/ass/path/to/project/stage4/output  ./input/`

My question, is there a way to change the root of the link or a trick a directory into thinking it's root without blocking off the rest of the filesystem, so that I can just type:

`ln -s /stage4/output ./input`

Comment: Why you don't use hard link if you are using one Hard Disk ?

Comment: I'm worried that if I write a malformed script that deletes the contents of the input folder, a hardlink would also delete the contents of file under the link. At least with softlinks, only the link is destroyed by my understanding